# Facebook resubmitting app for review not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests, facebook-app-center, facebook-app-settings

I'm trying to resubmit my live Facebook app for review but when I add permissions/features to resubmit, it just takes me to the app review page with no content inside it except for the header which is a link to facebook for developers main page.

Here is what appear on App review after I started resubmission (I removed the app name, but the APP ID is not shown from FB side on this page, however, it's shown again on other tabs like dashboard):

[image]

Comment: Check Settings -> Basic, any message there saying you currently can’t submit because stuff like business use selection or app icon missing …? _“and we can't afford for the app's permissions to be stopped”_ - good luck with that then … since the review process can currently take several weeks, you might have started rather late to care about this issue.

Comment: Thx for your quick response .. I checked and business use was missing but i filled it and still facing the problem.

Comment: I am not familiar with Facebook, but perhaps you could raise a support ticket to ask if there is a problem with their review system. It would probably be worth trying a different browser and a different connection first though.

Comment: @halfer, I tried to changing the browser and it didn't work .. however, I checked after a few hours and it got back to normal .. can't figure out what happened but at least now the permissions appear .. thx all ^_^